# Moving site to subdomain

Tags: siteurl

I am moving our current site to a subdomain and get this: "Craft CMS requires the PHP multibyte string extension in order to run."

I have updated the `$craftPath` variable and `System->General->SiteUrl` CP setting to the updated URL.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the site you're setting up on the subdomain is on a new server?

> Craft CMS requires the PHP multibyte string extension in order to run.

That error means that the PHP [multibyte extension](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) isn't installed or enabled on your server and both Craft 2 and Craft 3 require it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  It's actually on the same server - just a new subdomain.  I will check with our host and make sure it is setup.   I can move the website to the original domain and it works, its just when I move it to the subdomain.  I'll update with results from host.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's possible each subdomain has its own `php.ini` and the new one doesn't have `extension=mbstring.so`